# 27 column table that you can scroll horizontally to view

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-tablelayout, horizontalscrollview, tablerow

I know this has been answered in bits and pieces around this site, all my google links to questions similar to this one are purple, i've no other choice but to ask it here.

I want to make a table I can scroll left or right through, the problem I am encountering is that when I add multiple columns, instead of adding even sized columns, they just bunch up in the window, and the scrollview does nothing.  My .class code looks like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.table);
    }
```

My XML where I'm attempting to build this looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  

  <ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TableLayout  
     android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"  
     android:layout_width="match_parent"  
     android:layout_height="match_parent"  
     android:shrinkColumns="*"  
     android:stretchColumns="*">  
      <TableRow  
         android:id="@+id/tableRow4"  
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
         android:layout_width="match_parent"  
         android:gravity="center_horizontal">  
          <TextView  
              android:id="@+id/textView9"  
              android:layout_width="match_parent"  
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
              android:textStyle="bold"  
              android:typeface="serif"  
              android:textSize="18dp"  
              android:text="Argos Tracking Data"  
              android:gravity="center"  
              android:layout_span="6"></TextView>  
      </TableRow>  
      <TableRow  
         android:id="@+id/tableRow1"  
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
         android:layout_width="match_parent">  
        <TextView  
             android:id="@+id/TextView04"  
             android:text=""></TextView>  

          <TextView  
             android:id="@+id/TextView04"  
             android:text="Depth (FT)"
             android:textSize="11dp"
             android:textStyle="bold"  
             android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
           <TextView  
             android:id="@+id/TextView03"  
             android:text="Temp (ºC)" 
             android:textSize="11dp" 
             android:textStyle="bold"  
             android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  
           <TextView  
               android:id="@+id/TextView02"  
               android:text="Mag. Field  (nT)"
               android:textSize="11dp"  
               android:textStyle="bold"  
               android:typeface="serif"></TextView>  

                </TableRow>  


       <TableRow  
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
           android:id="@+id/tableRow2"  
           android:layout_width="match_parent">  
           <TextView  
              android:text="Day 1"  
              android:id="@+id/textView2"  
              android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>  
           <TextView  
               android:id="@+id/textView3"  
               android:text="28"  
               android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
           <TextView  
               android:text="37"  
               android:id="@+id/textView4"  
               android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
           <TextView  
               android:text="23°F"  
               android:id="@+id/textView5"  
               android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  


       </TableRow>  
      <TableRow  
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
          android:id="@+id/tableRow2"  
          android:layout_width="match_parent">  
          <TextView  
             android:text="Day 2"  
             android:id="@+id/textView2"  
             android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>  
           <TextView  
             android:text="15"  
             android:id="@+id/textView3"  
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
           <TextView  
             android:text="38"  
             android:id="@+id/textView4"                
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  
          <TextView  
             android:text="3°F"  
             android:id="@+id/textView5"  
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>  

           </TableRow>  


      <TableRow  
          android:id="@+id/tableRow3"  
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
          android:layout_width="match_parent"  
          android:gravity="center">

      </TableRow>  
 </TableLayout> 
</ScrollView>
```

I want to add more columns, but when I add more, the data just crams on the screen, it doesnt spread out evenly, and needless to say the way I have the code written in the XML, it won't scroll at all. Can someone aide me and show me where i'm going wrong here? Sorry If this is similar to other posts, i'm just stuck and can't manipulate any answers ive found to accomplish this. Thx

Answer (score 1):

ScrollView doesn't have an orientation attribute.
Just replace ScrollView with HorizontalScrollView